# Is there is option to evaluate values in nodejs without using eval or safe-eval?

Tags: node.js, npm, eval

I am trying to create a function in javascript having the same behavior as eval as it is not that much secure as safe-eval npm package. When I am trying to use safe-eval library rather than eval it doesn't support many of the functions as if, switch etc so it is giving me error as

SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

So I tried to write a code for same but facing some issues in that as well.

Is Anyone know how to use the safe-eval for condition execution or is anyone knows how to write a similar customized function/method for achieving the same goal.

thanks !!

Comment: Since you're asking about nodejs, why would you ever need to `eval` anything at all? `require` the code you control, and *never ever trust code you don't*, and certainly don't run it with the full permissions of your nodejs process. It should never be possible to execute something like `fs.readdirSync(__DIRNAME__).forEach(fs.unLink)` unless you explicitly wrote that yourself, in a normal file that you explicitly require and then call. What are you doing that you think you need on-demand evaluating for?

Answer (score 4):

The [safe-eval npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) says of the input:

> the JavaScript code must be an expression (something which evaluates to a value).

`if(...) { ... }` is a statement, not an expression.

The simple solution here is one that is already suggested by the documentation on that same NPM page: wrap your statements inside of a function expression that you immediately call.

```
var code = '(function square(b) { return b * b; })(5)'
var evaluated = safeEval(code)
```

You could put anything inside of that function, including statements:

```
var code = '(function square(b) { if(b === 5) { return "yes"; } else { return 0; } })(5)'
var evaluated = safeEval(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: (emphasis added)

> Currently, it works only with Node.js, and the JavaScript code **must be an expression (something which evaluates to a value)**.

`if` is a statement, not an expression.

You can make it evaluate statements by wrapping them in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), which is an expression.